# jQuery text() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$('#eform input').each(function() {
    if (this.className.indexOf('required') != -1) {
        $(this).closest('.rowElem').find('label').text(function(_, txt) {
            return '*' + txt
        });
    }
});
```

How could I return the asterisk in red.??

Comment: *"JavaScript text() Method"* JavaScript doesn't have a `text` method. jQuery does, though.

Comment: Wrap that in a `<span class="red">*<span> + txt` and provide the css to class `red`

Comment: You can't return a red asterix. But you could do: `$(this).closest('.rowElem').find('label').css("color", "red");` before you set the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return '<span style="color:red">*</span>' + txt
```

and use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: What I am doing wrong ? I print this from pl/sql using htp.p : htp.p('$(this).closest(".rowElem").find("label").html(function(_,txt) {return "<span style="color:red">*</span>" + txt});');

Comment: @user2795789 you need to escape the `color:red` quotation since they're in another quote block.  Try something like `style=\"color:red\"`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a text in **red** but wrap it in a `html` instead and return it; something like this should work for you:

```
$('#eform input').each(function() {
    if (this.className.indexOf('required') !== -1) {
        $(this).closest('.rowElem').find('label').html(function(_, txt) {
            return '<span style="color:red">*</span>' + txt;
        });
    }
});
```

I've used the `.html()` method instead of `.text()` for the purpose here.

Comment: and what if I have to wrap that code with '', for example htp.p('here the code');